# After Deserialize Object result have extra brackets

Tags: c#, json, ajax, post

Here is my data coming from ajax post.

```
string form = "[{\"id\": \"1\", \"name\": \"deneme\"},{\"id\": \"2\", \"name\": \"deneme2\"}]"
```

When I deserialize like this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(form);
```

The object is like this:

```
{ [{"id": 1, "name": "deneme"},{"id": 2, "name": "deneme2"}] }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Edit:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage ImportFromExcel(string form, string controller, string action)
        {
            //form = "[{\"id\": \"1\", \"name\": \"deneme\"},{\"id\": \"2\", \"name\": \"deneme2\"}]"
            ImportObject _importObject = new ImportObject();
            _importObject.SchemaName = controller;
            _importObject.TableName = action;

            var deger = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(form);
            //deger = { [{"id": 1, "name": "deneme"},{"id": 2, "name": "deneme2"}] } 
            Utility.HttpPostJson(proUtil.GetConfigStr("ApiImportUrl", ""), "Import", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_importObject));

            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }

public class ImportObject
{
    public string SchemaName { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public List<string> DataSet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How can it be an object without those?

Comment: I don't want the object, I want it to be an array

Comment: The second sample is after an object has been _serialized_. the first is an array, the second is an object with an array.If you just want the array then only serialize an array.

Comment: @AbdulvahapÖZTEL You already have the array. Use it from the de-serialized object.

Comment: How are you deserializing? You need to show us the code you use. Please [edit] that detail into your question.

Comment: like this : var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(form);

Comment: `{[...]}` is not JSON - so where do you see that?

Comment: When I run your code (using the sample string from your question and the `data` assignment from the comments), the result is a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`. Please show the exact code you're using.

Comment: `deger` is not a string... Sounds like you disagree with VS debugger showing of an object and not using JSON to do so. I'm afraid you'll have to settle for that - VS debugger just does not serialize objects to JSON to show them (and even if it would you'll have a lot more complains about escaped quotes in output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is:

```
var form = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(comingData.ToString());
foreach (var item in form)
{
    var cSharpClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(item.ToString());

    foreach (JProperty item2 in cSharpClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item2.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(item2.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are deserialising into JSON.Net objects instead of using a proper concrete class structure. I would recommend doing something like this. First make a class to hold your data:

```
public class FormItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now deserialise into an `IEnumerable<FormItem>` like this:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<FormItem>>(form);
```

And now you can loop through it as you would any other enumerable:

```
foreach(var formItem in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Item with id of {formItem.Id} has a name of {formItem.Name}");
}
```